# external and internal link generation in xls file using pear

Tags: php, pear, spreadsheet, xls

I wanted to generate xls file with multiple sheets. So, I took help from the below mentioned link.

http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer

Using the tutorial documentation from the same i was able to create multiple sheets in my xls file. i.e, in my test.xls file i was able to create sheet1, sheet2, sheet2 and so on.

Now, i want add a link in the content of sheet1 so that sheet2 displays the data. I was going through the Worksheet::writeUrl method. But, i failed to put links in the content.

**Sample code has been given below:**

```
require_once 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php';

$workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();

$workbook->send('test.xls');

$worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet('Report');
$worksheet1 =& $workbook->addWorksheet('John Smith');


$sheet = "John Smith";


$worksheet->write(0, 0, 'Name');
$worksheet->write(0, 1, 'Age');

$format =& $worksheet->writeUrl(1,0 ,"internal:".$sheet."!A1", $sheet);


$worksheet->write(1, 1, 30);
$worksheet->write(2, 0, 'Johann Schmidt');
$worksheet->write(2, 1, 31);
$worksheet->write(3, 0, 'Juan Herrera');
$worksheet->write(3, 1, 32);


$worksheet1->write(0, 0, 'Name');
$worksheet1->write(0, 1, 'Age');
$worksheet1->write(1, 0, 'aaaaaa');
$worksheet1->write(1, 1, 30);
$worksheet1->write(2, 0, 'bbbbb');
$worksheet1->write(2, 1, 31);
$worksheet1->write(3, 0, 'ccccc');
$worksheet1->write(3, 1, 32);


$workbook->close();
```

Please help me to add link.

Answer (score 1):

Your sheet name has a space, so it needs to be quoted in the hyperlink.
I can't recall if that means

```
'internal:John Smith'!A1
```

or

```
internal:'John Smith'!A1
```

suspect the latter, but I haven't actually checked

Comment: Sorry but i cant find any space in the sheet name. I have used the sheet name as "JohnSmith" as well to check.

Comment: After a lot of modification i found that, if i open the file using Microsoft Excel, the link of excel sheet works successfully. But, in LibreOffice (open source), the link is not working.

Comment: **internal:'John Smith'!A1** works indeed. - That is in MS Excel. OpenOffice won't interpret it as link, it will just display a blue underlined text cell.